# Disable command option pop-up in WinEdt while leaving the command suggestion pop-up enabled

Tags: winedt, auto-completion

I am using WinEdt version 10.3 on Windows 10. While you start typing a latex command, a window pops up with suggestions:

[image: Pop-up 1]

And once you enter/select the correct command/environment, then there is another pop-up:

[image: Pop-up 2]

How can one disable the 2nd pop-up? Ideally I would like to have the first pop-up still enabled.

Comment: You should take a look at the WinEdt macro that's responsible for this behaviour and see if it can easily be modified.

Comment: Thanks - it seems it is the "completenv.edt" macro in winedt. As of now I have zero understanding of the winedt macro language, so will take me a while to follow your suggestion ...

Comment: In which directory did you find this macro? (I'm the author of the  `MathGreek` set of WinEdt macros).

Comment: C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Macros\Active Strings

Comment: I'll try to see that tomorrow (it's getting late here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Main Menu -> Options -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Line Numbers, then remove your file type (tex?) from the list under "Show line numbers for modes".

Comment: Tried this just now - does not have any effect on the pop-ups.

Comment: @user25216: the reason can be that WinEdt has already associated your file with the line numbering mode (when you created it or opened for first time). Try to remove TEX from the list, as explained in my answer, then exit WinEdt, rename your file, and reopen it anew in WinEdt, under the brand new name.